# How to create a stacked barchart using d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, bar-chart

I have an object array:

```
var data = [
  {"ORDER": 1, "apples": 3840, "bananas": 1920, "cherries": 960},
  {"ORDER": 2, "apples": 1600, "bananas": 1440, "cherries": 960},
  {"ORDER": 3, "apples":  640, "bananas":  960, "cherries": 640},
  {"ORDER": 4, "apples":  320, "bananas":  480, "cherries": 640}
];
```

I want to create a stacked bar chart so that the orders are on the x axis and the total of apples, bananas, and cherries are the y axis.
Here is my code so far:

```
x = d3.scaleOrdinal().range([0, w-50])
y = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, h-50])

var stack = d3.stack()
    .keys(["apples", "bananas", "cherries", "dates"])
    .order(d3.stackOrderNone)
    .offset(d3.stackOffsetNone);

var series = stack(data);

 x.domain(series.map(function(d) { return d.Order; }));
 y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d; })]).nice();

g.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(d3.stack()(series))
    .enter().append("g")
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.key); })
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Order); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
        .attr("width", x);
```

I am also appending it to an svg but I know the problem is in the code above. Any ideas on what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues present.

One, your data for the chart is already ready stacked in `series`:

```
var series = stack(data);
```

This: `d3.stack()(series);` will produce an empty array:

```js
var data = [
  {"ORDER": 1, "apples": 3840, "bananas": 1920, "cherries": 960},
  {"ORDER": 2, "apples": 1600, "bananas": 1440, "cherries": 960},
  {"ORDER": 3, "apples":  640, "bananas":  960, "cherries": 640},
  {"ORDER": 4, "apples":  320, "bananas":  480, "cherries": 640}
];
var stack = d3.stack()
    .keys(["apples", "bananas", "cherries"])
    .order(d3.stackOrderNone)
    .offset(d3.stackOffsetNone);
var series = stack(data);
console.log(d3.stack()(series));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.6.0/d3.js"></script>
```

---

Further down:

```
 .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Order); })
```

This will return undefined. First, your property is `ORDER` not `Order`, and secondly, if you `console.log(d)` before that return, you'll notice that the property order is located at: `d.data.ORDER`.

This is also an issue with your scale:

```
 x.domain(series.map(function(d) { return d.Order; }));
```

For your x scale domain, you should use your `data` variable to map out the x domain:  `x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.ORDER; }));`.

---

Speaking of scales, your width is best defined with a `scaleBand()` [(documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#scaleBand)) rather than a `scaleOrdinal()`, this will allow you to set the width with `x.bandwidth()`.

Lastly, still speaking of scales:
For your y scale, your domain will not work properly, if using [this bl.ock as an example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208), you'll see the creation of a `total` property that will define the upper end of the domain. So you will need to find a way to get the total of all the properties you want to graph for each `ORDER`. I've used an arbitrary 10 000 as the upper limit to produce a working example (I also don't know your color function, so I've just used an array):

```js
var data = [
  {"ORDER": 1, "apples": 3840, "bananas": 1920, "cherries": 960},
  {"ORDER": 2, "apples": 1600, "bananas": 1440, "cherries": 960},
  {"ORDER": 3, "apples":  640, "bananas":  960, "cherries": 640},
  {"ORDER": 4, "apples":  320, "bananas":  480, "cherries": 640}
];

var h = 200;
var w = 200;
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width',w).attr('height',h);
var g = svg.append('g');


var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, w-50]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([h-50, 0]).domain([0,10000]);
var color = ['#bae4bc','#7bccc4','#43a2ca'];

var stack = d3.stack()
    .keys(["apples", "bananas", "cherries"])
    .order(d3.stackOrderNone)
    .offset(d3.stackOffsetNone);
    
var series = stack(data);

x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.ORDER; }));

g.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(series)
    .enter().append("g")
        .attr("fill", function(d,i) { return color[i]; })
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.ORDER); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.6.0/d3.js"></script>
```