# Stacked chart with data array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I try to create stacked bar chart like https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1134768. But I don't want to use .tsv file

How can I create the stacked bar chart with an array like below?

```
var data=[
    {date:'Jan',total:100, disease:20, wounds: 5,  other: 10},
    {date:'Feb',total:200, disease:25, wounds: 10, other: 20}   
];
```

Any suggestion should be appreciated.

Comment: https://codepen.io/edisonpappi/pen/zPwgVj

Comment: Look at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42430484/5806646 It may help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the steps for the bl.ocks you linked (have in mind that, since you didn't provide **your** code, I'll write the answer to that bl.ocks specifically):

1. Hardcode your data:

   ```
   var crimea = [{
       date: "4/1854",
       total: "8571",
       disease: "1",
       wounds: "0",
       other: "5"
   }, {
       date: "5/1854",
       total: "23333",
       disease: "12",
       wounds: "0",
       other: "9"
   },
   etc...
   ]
   ```
2. Move the row function to a `forEach` loop:

   ```
   crimea.forEach(function(d) {
       d.date = parseDate(d.date);
       causes.forEach(function(c) {
           d[c] = +d[c];
       });
   })
   ```
3. Get rid of the TSV.

This is the code with those changes:

```html
<style>
  .axis text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
  }
  
  .axis line,
  .axis path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }
  
  .axis--x path {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var causes = ["wounds", "other", "disease"];

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%Y").parse;

    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 20
      },
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .rangeRoundBands([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .rangeRound([height, 0]);

    var z = d3.scale.category10();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom")
      .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%b"));

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("right");

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var crimea = [{
        date: "4/1854",
        total: "8571",
        disease: "1",
        wounds: "0",
        other: "5"
      },
      {
        date: "5/1854",
        total: "23333",
        disease: "12",
        wounds: "0",
        other: "9"
      },
      {
        date: "6/1854",
        total: "28333",
        disease: "11",
        wounds: "0",
        other: "6"
      },
      {
        date: "7/1854",
        total: "28772",
        disease: "359",
        wounds: "0",
        other: "23"
      },
      {
        date: "8/1854",
        total: "30246",
        disease: "828",
        wounds: "1",
        other: "30"
      },
      {
        date: "9/1854",
        total: "30290",
        disease: "788",
        wounds: "81",
        other: "70"
      },
      {
        date: "10/1854",
        total: "30643",
        disease: "503",
        wounds: "132",
        other: "128"
      },
      {
        date: "11/1854",
        total: "29736",
        disease: "844",
        wounds: "287",
        other: "106"
      },
      {
        date: "12/1854",
        total: "32779",
        disease: "1725",
        wounds: "114",
        other: "131"
      },
      {
        date: "1/1855",
        total: "32393",
        disease: "2761",
        wounds: "83",
        other: "324"
      },
      {
        date: "2/1855",
        total: "30919",
        disease: "2120",
        wounds: "42",
        other: "361"
      },
      {
        date: "3/1855",
        total: "30107",
        disease: "1205",
        wounds: "32",
        other: "172"
      },
      {
        date: "4/1855",
        total: "32252",
        disease: "477",
        wounds: "48",
        other: "57"
      },
      {
        date: "5/1855",
        total: "35473",
        disease: "508",
        wounds: "49",
        other: "37"
      },
      {
        date: "6/1855",
        total: "38863",
        disease: "802",
        wounds: "209",
        other: "31"
      },
      {
        date: "7/1855",
        total: "42647",
        disease: "382",
        wounds: "134",
        other: "33"
      },
      {
        date: "8/1855",
        total: "44614",
        disease: "483",
        wounds: "164",
        other: "25"
      },
      {
        date: "9/1855",
        total: "47751",
        disease: "189",
        wounds: "276",
        other: "20"
      },
      {
        date: "10/1855",
        total: "46852",
        disease: "128",
        wounds: "53",
        other: "18"
      },
      {
        date: "11/1855",
        total: "37853",
        disease: "178",
        wounds: "33",
        other: "32"
      },
      {
        date: "12/1855",
        total: "43217",
        disease: "91",
        wounds: "18",
        other: "28"
      },
      {
        date: "1/1856",
        total: "44212",
        disease: "42",
        wounds: "2",
        other: "48"
      },
      {
        date: "2/1856",
        total: "43485",
        disease: "24",
        wounds: "0",
        other: "19"
      },
      {
        date: "3/1856",
        total: "46140",
        disease: "15",
        wounds: "0",
        other: "35"
      }
    ];

    crimea.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
      causes.forEach(function(c) {
        d[c] = +d[c];
      });
    })

    var layers = d3.layout.stack()(causes.map(function(c) {
      return crimea.map(function(d) {
        return {
          x: d.date,
          y: d[c]
        };
      });
    }));

    x.domain(layers[0].map(function(d) {
      return d.x;
    }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(layers[layers.length - 1], function(d) {
      return d.y0 + d.y;
    })]).nice();

    var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
      .data(layers)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "layer")
      .style("fill", function(d, i) {
        return z(i);
      });

    layer.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.x);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.y + d.y0);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0);
      })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand() - 1);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ",0)")
      .call(yAxis);
  </script>
```

Comment: @Greardo when i try to change 'orient' of y axis from 'right' to 'left' then it's y axis position doesn't change , only label position is changing.

Comment: @kunal please, don't ask further questions in the comments. As this is a different issue, please post *another* question. However, just to let you know, you have to change the transform here: `.attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ",0)")`. Change `width` for the value you want.

Comment: @Greardo Check my another question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47278372/stacked-chart-with-data-array-in-d3-js) related to existing query