# Stacked chart with data array in d3 js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have try to customize my existing code of Stacked Bar graph with the help of this link
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1134768.

I have done this graph with the help of given link but i have some confusion about the data points on y axis as shown below in picture

[image: Stacked Bar]

Here is my full code of Stacked bar Graph

```
var data = [
    {month: 'Jan',total:100 ,A: 35, B: 5, C: 10},
    {month: 'Feb',total:200 ,A: 30, B: 10, C: 20},
    {month: 'Mar',total:300 ,A: 0, B: 10, C: 20}
];

var xData = ["A", "B", "C"];

var margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .35);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
      .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

data.forEach(function(d) {
      xData.forEach(function(c) {
        d[c] = +d[c];}); })

var dataIntermediate = xData.map(function (c) {
    return data.map(function (d) {
        return {x: d.month, y: d[c]};});});

var dataStackLayout = d3.layout.stack()(dataIntermediate);

x.domain(dataStackLayout[0].map(function (d) {
    return d.x; }));

y.domain([0,d3.max(dataStackLayout[dataStackLayout.length - 1],
            function (d) { return d.y0 + d.y;}) ]).nice();

var layer = svg.selectAll(".stack")
        .data(dataStackLayout)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "stack")
        .style("fill", function (d, i) {
            console.info(i, color(i));
            return color(i);});

layer.selectAll("rect")
        .data(function (d) {
            return d;})
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            console.info("dx", d.x,x(d.x), x.rangeBand());
            return x(d.x);})
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.y + d.y0);})
        .attr("height", function (d) {               
            return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0); })
        .attr("width", x.rangeBand() -1);

svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);  

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(yAxis)
       .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end");
```

As i have taken help from the given url, i have change my code which take array data as input instead of CSV file. But i think my data points(label) on y axis is not according to given data(key:total).

Any help should be appreciated.

Comment: What is you are actually trying to achieve ? Your questions is a bit unclear. Can please explain more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution about my confusion on how can i show the total count on y axis
because in my array data there is key 'total' which is total count of all states such as 'A','B' & 'C' shown in array data

```
    var data = [
    {month: "4/1854",total:"100" ,A: "45", B:"45", C:"10"},
    {month: "5/1854",total:"200" ,A:"80", B:"70", C:"50"},
    {month: "6/1854",total:"300" ,A:"0", B:"100", C:"200"}
];
```

So as there is a total key in array data and i have to show as label on y axis.Here is my full code

```
 var data = [
    {month: "4/1854",total:"100" ,A: "45", B:"45", C:"10"},
    {month: "5/1854",total:"200" ,A:"80", B:"70", C:"50"},
    {month: "6/1854",total:"300" ,A:"0", B:"100", C:"200"}
];

var xData = ["A", "B", "C"];

  var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%Y").parse;

var margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 350 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .35);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category20();
//console.info(color(0));

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%b"));

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
      .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("#pie").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.month = parseDate(d.month);
      xData.forEach(function(c) {
        d[c] = +d[c];
      });

    })

var dataIntermediate = xData.map(function (c) {
    return data.map(function (d) {
        return {x: d.month, y: d[c]};
    });
});

var dataStackLayout = d3.layout.stack()(dataIntermediate);

x.domain(dataStackLayout[0].map(function (d) {
    return d.x;
}));

y.domain([0,
   d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })
    ])
  .nice();

var layer = svg.selectAll(".stack")
        .data(dataStackLayout)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "stack")
        .style("fill", function (d, i) {
            console.info(i, color(i));
            return color(i);
        });

layer.selectAll("rect")
        .data(function (d) {
            return d;
        })
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            console.info("dx", d.x,x(d.x), x.rangeBand());
            return x(d.x);
        })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.y + d.y0);
        })
        .attr("height", function (d) {
            // console.info(d.y0, d.y, y(d.y0), y(d.y))
            return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0);
        })
        .attr("width", x.rangeBand() -1);


svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(yAxis)
       .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are trying to add a new dataset with key "total", try to add key "total" in your xData array like following and it should be Visible on chart.

```
var xData = ["total", "A", "B", "C"];
```

Comment: as i have mention in my question that i have done my graph by using this link [link](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1134768) , so they have also access  the key 'total' without mentioning in 'xData=[]'

Comment: No they don't, I believe they are only showing wounds, disease and other.

Comment: then what  they are trying to do with key:'total' ?

Comment: they just added it to the data set so that if anyone want to see the total number then he can get it from the data. they are not showing it on bars chart.